# Reasonable to create and accept new answer after edit request to add code example rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

[The suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8561668).

I made the change to add an example of using the `ReadWriteLock`, the library class which was suggested in Dim's answer.

Many answers have code examples in them - it makes them easier to understand, and is more useful than just linking to the library documentation. It is however a significant edit to the content, not a change in presentation or correction of an error, so the rejection makes sense.

I could create a new answer with the given example and mark it as accepted - but that doesn't feel fair as Dim's answer is correct, and I accepted it years ago.

Would unaccepting the current answer and adding a new one with a code example be rude? The code example is too large to put in a comment.

Comment: http://gist.github.com you can format using markdown, post the revised answer in a new gist and include that in a comment explaining why you think it is better. If, after a reasonable amount of time has passed, the user  doesn't respond then post your new answer and accept it. There's nothing you can do about users ignoring their old posts.

Comment: _It is however a significant edit to the content_ I think the deal is that they don't want us adding code or code results to posts that aren't from the OP themselves, no matter the size of the edit.

Comment: Also, you can always vote up the answer when you remove the accept so the OP doesn't take as much of a hit to their reputation.